# Excel Worksheet updates so slow

Tags: excel, vba, performance

Im creating a questionnaire with pop-ups, etc. For some countries (E25), there will be an extra question (hence sumX = 17 or 16). At the end, there should be 3 different possible answers (A35, A45, A55), each colour coded at the end. The code works splendidly with one caveat: it is too slow and every time the user changes his/her answer, the code must reload and that slows down the excel. Is there a workaround to this? The code is shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim KeyCells2 As Range
'Regelmäßigkeit
Set KeyCells = Sheet1.Range("A1:M157")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

If Sheet1.Range("L38").Value = "Nein" Then
    Sheet1.Rows("42:44").Hidden = True
   
ElseIf Sheet1.Range("L38").Value = "Ja" Then
    Sheet1.Rows("42:44").Hidden = False
    
End If

'Keine extra Frage
If Sheet1.Range("C99").Value = "17. Bitte beachten Sie folgende Besonderheiten:" Then
    Sheet1.Rows("98:103").Hidden = True
'Extra Frage
ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C99").Value <> "17. Bitte beachten Sie folgende Besonderheiten:" Then
    Sheet1.Rows("98:103").Hidden = False

End If

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sumX As Long
Dim result As String
Dim sumXY As Long


'Keine Extra Frage
If Sheet1.Rows("98:103").Hidden = True Then

'Unvollständig
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("P1:P97"), "X") > 0 Then
    Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A55").Value
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("P1:P97"), "X") = 0 Then

        'Check if the value in E25 is in Sheet2 column G
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("H3:H229"), Sheet1.Range("E25").Value) > 0 Then
            'If the value is found, sum the values in O1:O98
            sumX = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("O1:O97"), "X")


            If sumX = 16 Then
                'Wenn Summe gleich 16 ist, dann genehmigt
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A35").Value
            ElseIf sumX < 16 Then
                'Wenn Summe ungleich 16 ist, dann mit Vorbehalt
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A45").Value
            End If
        Else
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A45").Value
        End If
End If

'Extra Frage
ElseIf Sheet1.Rows("98:103").Hidden = False Then

'Unvollständig
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("P1:P99"), "X") > 0 Then
    Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A55").Value

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("P1:P99"), "X") = 0 Then

        'Check if the value in E25 is in Sheet2 column G
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("H3:H229"), Sheet1.Range("E25").Value) > 0 Then
            'If the value is found, sum the values in O1:O98
            sumX = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("O1:O99"), "X")
    
            If sumX = 17 Then
                'Wenn Summe gleich 17 ist, dann genehmigt
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A35").Value
            ElseIf sumX < 17 Then
                'Wenn Summe ungleich 17 ist, dann mit Vorbehalt
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A45").Value
            End If
        Else
                Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A45").Value

        End If
End If
End If
End If

'Colour coding
If Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A35").Value Then
Sheet1.Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A45").Value Then
Sheet1.Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
ElseIf Sheet1.Range("C106").Value = Sheet2.Range("A55").Value Then
Sheet1.Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 46
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: In your `If` blocks you repeatedly read from the sheet to test each case - it would be cleaner to first read the cell/calculation into a variable, and use that variable in your  `If` tests.  Also - does every check in that Sub really need to run for any change to any cell in A1:M157, or could you check smaller ranges for some of the steps?  Also - `Application.Screenupdating = False` at the beginning of the updates would help speed thing up.

Comment: If for example : there is "X" within P1:P97 ---> so then the code put A55 value to C106. Soon after it put the value to C106, it will goes back to the beginning of the sub. Is this intentional ? If not, then I think you should put `application.enableevents=false` in order the sub won't go back to the beginning of the sub each time the sub itself make a change on the sheet.

Comment: Both Application.Screenupdating = False and application.enableevents=false help speed things up when I put them on the top, the problem now is that there are no results changing. Sorry I only just started programming

Comment: Have you also added the `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end? Have you changed your code to what Tim said about putting your cell values into variables and comparing from there? (you can place an eddited version of your sub below in your post underneath everything so others can follow the transition). Also, no need to apologize for being new to something (or being less experienced).

Comment: Thanks for the positive input. It works much quicker now because I put only Application.Screenupdating = False at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Because the code for the -Change event- changes the same sheet, will re-execute... I think using Application.ScreenUpdating = False is necessary but something more is needed. You will test Application.EnableEvents = False with error catching so that we are sure that at the end of the SUB it will fall back to Application.EnableEvents = True. Besides these I have made some improvements so that the same commands are not executed multiple times. I have placed comments inside the code. I believe the code runs in SHEET1 so the explicit reference is not needed. The last block that changes the colors is also outside the control block: If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then ... End if, and is executed with any change in the sheet. I think you should move it inside the block since the colors are affected by the value of cell C106. Even inside the mlpok the color code will run for each change in the range: <Set KeyCells = Range("A1:M157")>. But since the colors are associated with the value of C106 I think we should limit the execution of the color changing code to only when C106 changes. The question here is does C106 only change within this SUB, or can the user also change it? Since I don't know I've added a Boolean variable to check if the colors need to be changed in each case. So test the code and if it works you can delete the unused code.

```
Option Explicit    'Always use it. In the first line of the module

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range
   Dim KeyCells2 As Range
   Dim ToHide As String, ToShow As String
   Dim sh2A35 As Variant, sh2A45 As Variant, sh2A55 As Variant  'if want, change the type according the type of the data in cells
   Dim c106 As Range, cologChange As Boolean
   Dim SEP As String  'you can replase the list separator with "," or ";" (depents on system settings) and delete this line
   
   Const STR1 = "17. Bitte beachten Sie folgende Besonderheiten:"
   Const rowsA = "A42:A44"
   Const rowsB = "A98:A103"
   
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False   'until the end of this SUB don't refresh the screen
   Application.EnableEvents = False 'stop triggering events until set it to true. TO BE SURE HAVE TO CATCH ERRORS
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo LERROR
   
   SEP = Application.International(xlListSeparator)
   'because i dont know your settings i use the above line to get the List separator.
   'If you want delete all SEP declaretion and references and replace SEP with one of: "," or ";"
   
   'Regelma?igkeit
   Set KeyCells = Range("A1:M157")
   'BLOCK-A THREE LINES NEW CODE        'BLOCK-A
   sh2A35 = SHEET2.Range("A35").value   'BLOCK-A
   sh2A45 = SHEET2.Range("A45").value   'BLOCK-A
   sh2A55 = SHEET2.Range("A55").value   'BLOCK-A
   
   Set c106 = Range("C106")
   
   If Not Application.Intersect(Target, c106) Is Nothing Then cologChange = True
   
   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
   
      'ALTERNATE POSITION OF BLOCK-A
   
      With Range("L38")
         If .value = "Nein" Then
            'Rows("42:44").Hidden = True
            ToHide = ToHide & IIf(ToHide = "", "", SEP) & rowsA
            
         ElseIf .value = "Ja" Then
            'Rows("42:44").Hidden = False
            ToShow = ToShow & IIf(ToShow = "", "", SEP) & rowsA
         End If
      End With
      'Keine extra Frage
      If Range("C99").value = STR1 Then
         'Rows("98:103").Hidden = True
         ToHide = ToHide & IIf(ToHide = "", "", SEP) & rowsB
         'Extra Frage
      'ElseIf SHEET1.Range("C99").value <> STR1 Then
      Else 'you don't need any check because if equal ok, else is not equal (without check)
         'Rows("98:103").Hidden = False
         ToShow = ToShow & IIf(ToShow = "", "", SEP) & rowsB
      End If
      
      If ToHide <> vbNullString Then Range(ToHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True
      If ToShow <> vbNullString Then Range(ToShow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
      
      Dim lastRow As Long
      Dim sumX As Long
      Dim result As String
      Dim sumXY As Long
      Dim sumTmpP As Variant, sumTmpH As Variant  'change the type according the type of the data
      
      'Keine Extra Frage
      'If SHEET1.Rows("98:103").Hidden = True Then
      With c106
         If Rows("98:103").Hidden = True Then
            
            'Unvollstandig
            sumTmpP = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("P1:P97"), "X")
            If sumTmpP > 0 Then
               cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A55)
               .value = sh2A55
            ElseIf sumTmpP = 0 Then
               
               'Check if the value in E25 is in Sheet2 column G
               If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SHEET2.Range("H3:H229"), SHEET1.Range("E25").value) > 0 Then
                  'If the value is found, sum the values in O1:O98
                  sumX = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("O1:O97"), "X")
                  
                  If sumX = 16 Then
                     'Wenn Summe gleich 16 ist, dann genehmigt
                     cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A35)
                     .value = sh2A35
                  ElseIf sumX < 16 Then
                     'Wenn Summe ungleich 16 ist, dann mit Vorbehalt
                     cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A45)
                     .value = sh2A45
                  End If
               Else
                   cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A45)
                  .value = sh2A45
               End If
            End If
            
            'Extra Frage
         ElseIf Rows("98:103").Hidden = False Then
            
            'Unvollstandig
            sumTmpP = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("P1:P99"), "X")
            If sumTmpP > 0 Then
               cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A55)
               .value = sh2A55
               
            ElseIf sumTmpP = 0 Then
               
               'Check if the value in E25 is in Sheet2 column G
               If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(SHEET2.Range("H3:H229"), SHEET1.Range("E25").value) > 0 Then
                  'If the value is found, sum the values in O1:O98
                  sumX = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("O1:O99"), "X")
                  
                  If sumX = 17 Then
                     'Wenn Summe gleich 17 ist, dann genehmigt
                     cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A35)
                     .value = sh2A35
                  ElseIf sumX < 17 Then
                     'Wenn Summe ungleich 17 ist, dann mit Vorbehalt
                     cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A45)
                     .value = sh2A45
                  End If
               Else
                  cologChange = cologChange Or (.value <> sh2A45)
                  .value = sh2A45

               End If
            End If
         End If
      End With
      
      'I THINK THAT THE NEXT BLOCK OF CODE LEBELED  'Colour coding'  as i changed it, HAVE TO MOVE HERE
      'unless the SHEET1.Range("C106").value is changed somewhere else, with some other code
      
      'If finally move the ('Colour coding' as i changed to 'BLOCK-B TEN LINES ALTERNATE CODE)  here then move and the
      'BLOCK-A THREE LINES NEW CODE  in position labeled 'ALTERNATE POSITION OF BLOCK-A
      
   End If
   
   'Colour coding
'   If Range("C106").value = sh2A35 Then
'      Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 43
'   ElseIf Range("C106").value = sh2A45 Then
'      Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 44
'   ElseIf Range("C106").value = sh2A55 Then
'      Range("C106").Interior.ColorIndex = 46
'   End If

   'BLOCK-B TEN LINES ALTERNATE CODE
   If cologChange Then
      With c106.Interior
         Select Case c106.value
         Case sh2A35
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 43
         Case sh2A45
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
         Case sh2A55
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 46
         End Select
      End With
   End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True  'if the code has no error set it back to true
   Exit Sub
LERROR:
   Application.EnableEvents = True  'if the code HAS errors set it back to true
   On Error GoTo 0
   MsgBox ("ERROR IN Worksheet_Change of sheet " & Me.Name & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number: " & Err.Number)
End Sub
```